# Etymology of reduplicative compound "nitty-gritty"

Tags: etymology, american-english

I've always been curious about that one and I've come across  many contending theories for the etymology of *nitty-gritty*.  English is quite fond of these *reduplicative compounds*.

I'd like to know whether some consensus has been achieved in this area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alain, as you have done me so much service with your etymologies, I simply must do you one ;)

*Nitty-gritty* comes by way of African-American culture, southern and south-western African-American culture to be exact,
and the word was attested orally as early as the 1920s.  Let me quote from a paper, [*The Real
Nitty Gritty*](http://www.jstor.org/pss/3087921) by a W. R. Higginbotham and J.A., from whence nearly all my information comes:

> The  earliest  uses  of  nitty-gritty are  in  registers  characteristic of  black America,  and
>   they  continue: jazz  music and  musicians (1961, 1963a, 1965, 1966a,  1969c,  1971c), civil rights
>   and black power  (1963b, c, 1966d,1967c, d, 1968a, b, 1970d), and as an ingredient in that elusive
>   quality that  pervades and identifies all things black-soul (1966a, b,  1967b, 1969b, d).
>
> <sub>The citations are left in without a bibliography, so that you may see the date of first attestation.</sub>

From African-American culture, it then apparently passed into the lingo of college students at about
the time of the 1960s, by way of popular music, and was probably helped in its adoption by the
general countercultural mood of that era. (Remember this was the era of "the [Civil Rights]
struggle"; knowing the obscure argot of an oppressed people would have likely seemed appealingly
dangerous and sexy to college students.)  From there, it spread into the general culture via writers and
high-circulation periodicals, such as *The New York Times* and *Newsweek*.  One song written in
1963, by a Licoln Chase, titled simply *The Nitty Gritty*, appears to have been especially
influential in the uptake of the word.  I reproduce the first few lines:

> Some folks know about it, some don't.
>   Some will learn to shout it, some won't.
>   But soon or later, baby, here's a ditty,
>   Say you're gonna have to get right down to the real NITTY GRITTY.
>   Let's get right down to the real NITTY GRITTY,
>   now one, two NITTY GRITTY,
>   now yeah, boom NITTY GRITTY,
>   now ooooh-iee. Right down to the real NITTY GRITTY!
>   Oooh-oooh! Oooh-oooh!

More from the paper:

> The  word  seems to  have  been  first used  as  a  noun (1961-63);  and,  although it  passed
>   easily and early in its recorded history into  adjectival use (1964b,  1966d,  1967c, d,  1968a,
>   1969e,  f,  1971a,  1973c), it  has  remained predominantly a  noun.  Indeed,  by far the most
>   frequent collocation of the term is some form of the expression *get right down to the real
>   nitty-gritty*, which, in  one  variant  or  another,  accounts  for about  half of  the  total
>   number  of citations.  That  phrase also  accounts  for  the  earliest uses.

But you're probably wondering how this phrasing *get down to the nitty gritty* was coined
originally. Well, here's where it gets disgusting.  In fairness, there is actually some disagreement
about the following explanation in the paper -- Higginbotham promotes the idea in the beginning,
while J.A. argues against it -- but it is easily the most intriguing one I found therein, so I must
reproduce it. Apparently, the "nitty" in *nitty gritty* refers to *actual nits*, as in lice, and the
*gritty* was initially a reference to ground [hominy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hominy), and then
became a reference the grinding action one uses to reproduce the staple. Of course, that in turn was easily
sexualized in meaning so that *gritty* also came to describe the grinding action of raw, bestial
intercourse.  Thus, *getting down to the nitty-gritty* means getting down so deep in a woman that
one feels everything of her movements, and I do mean everything.  The paper gives this joke to illustrate:

> Both  black men  at  Amarillo insisted  to  me  that  nitty gritty sprang from what they described
>   as  an  old,  black,  nearly  pointless joke that  goes:
>
> *A man  having intercourse with a smart-alecky girl took  an  unusually  long stroke, making her jump.
>    Thinking  he  had impressed her, he  asked, "Did I  hit it,  honey?"  "Yeah,"  she  said.  "Wrong
>   way.  You  hit  the  real nitty gritty."*

Wow! Amazing language, our English.

Comment: Sweet. Here's [Shirley Ellis singing "The Nitty Gritty," 1963.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKD1OpoyF9o)

Comment: The phrases.org link lists a song "That Nitty Gritty Dance" in 1937  - It's interesting how long slang terms can be around before being reported in print, especially presumably black slang in the US

Comment: +1.  I liked the article "The Real Nitty Gritty" you have linked. The atmosphere of the motel lobbies is so well depicted that you can almost feel like you're an invisible witness in the room.

Comment: @mgb: And it's particularly interesting that the first two lines of _The Nitty Gritty_ articulate the phenomenon of which you speak.